# SFINAE for user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, sfinae

There is really no background about this question.

There are many ways using SFINAE (directly or indirectly with type_traits) to check for an existing function, a member function, and so on. But:

**First Question**: Is there any way to check if a class implements a specific user-defined conversion operator?

To illustrate what I mean, consider this code. I would like to run this code without any assertion failing:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

struct NotADouble {
};
struct Double {
    // explicit or not - you decide
    explicit operator double() {
        return 1.;
    }
};
// CORRECT THIS: ...
template<typename T,
    class = decltype(static_cast<double>(std::declval<T>()))>
int f(T) {
    return 1;
}
int f(...) {
    return 2;
}
// ... UNTIL HERE

int main() {
    assert(f(NotADouble()) == 2);
    assert(f(Double()) == 1);
    assert(f(3.) == 2);
    assert(f(3) == 2);
    assert(f(3.f) == 2);
}
```

The current implementation of `f` checks whether there is any standard conversion sequence from `T` to `double`, I assume this is the same as `std::is_convertible` in this case.

Another approach would be the following implementation, which accepts the first two tests.

```
template<typename T>
int f(T, double (T::*)() = nullptr) {
    return 1;
}
int f(...) {
    return 2;
}
```

**Question 2**: Even though NotADouble does not implement any conversion operator, it seems to allow this member function pointer. Therefore, what exactly is `double (T::*)()` and why does it exist for any class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question:** you could create helper struct to check if there is defined conversion operator in a given structure (c++14 code):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct NotDouble { };
struct Double {
   explicit operator double() {
       return 1.0;
   }
};

template <class From, class To, class = void>
struct HasConversionOperator: std::false_type { };

template <class From, class To>
struct HasConversionOperator<From, To, decltype((&From::operator To), void())>: std::true_type { };

template <class From, class To, class = void>
struct HasExplicitConversion: std::false_type {};

template <class From, class To>
struct HasExplicitConversion<From, To, decltype(std::declval<To&>() = (To)std::declval<From&>(), void())>: std::true_type { };

template <class From, class To, class = void>
struct HasImplicitConversion: std::false_type {};

template <class From, class To>
struct HasImplicitConversion<From, To, decltype(std::declval<To&>() = std::declval<From&>(), void())>: std::true_type { };

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<HasConversionOperator<T, double>::value && HasExplicitConversion<T, double>::value && !HasImplicitConversion<T, double>::value> is_double(T d) {
   std::cout << "has conversion to double" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<!HasConversionOperator<T, double>::value || !HasExplicitConversion<T, double>::value || HasImplicitConversion<T, double>::value> is_double(T) {
   std::cout << "don't have conversion to double" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   is_double(Double{});
   is_double(NotDouble{});
}
```

Output:

> ```
> has conversion to double
> don't have conversion to double
> ```

**Second question:** `double (T::*)()` is a type of any member function pointer with owner `T` that returns a double that does not take any parameters. Have in mind that not only conversion operators have such signature. What is more even if the class T does not have any member function that returns double and takes no parameter it is perfectly allowed to create such pointer type, one just won't be able to fill variable of the pointer type with any value...

Comment: There was  similar test I tried, but without the reference, which clearly was not enough...

Comment: @user3445587 You mean `address of` operator (&). Yes unfortunately there is no way to take member function reference, which is clearly a drawback, but it is directly due to the c++ method call syntax. E.g. in the `a.foo();` how `foo` should be interpreted? As a member function of `a` or the member function reference available in the scope...?